# Splitting up an angle between two degree values

Tags: java, math

I have two angles given to me; a starting one and an ending one.
I'm also in a loop with a specified numbers of loops.

I'm trying to split an angle up so at each loop iteration I create something at that angle.

Using 3 particles as an example

Here is the code (within in the loop, degrees are 90 to 180)

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParticles(3); i++)
{
    float percentage = 1f / numberOfParticles;
    percentage *= index;
    float angle = startingAngle + ((endingAngle - startingAngle) * percentage);
}
```

My problem is this produces : (instead of 90 (0), 135 (0.5), 180 (1))

```
Log: 90.0 | percentage: 0.0
Log: 120.0 | percentage: 0.33333334
Log: 149.99998 | percentage: 0.6666667
```

How would I get this to work with any number (including 7?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an off-by-one error. If you have 3 particles, you're going to start at 0% and then add 50% 2 times, not 3.

```
float percentage = 1f / (numberOfParticles - 1);
```

Make sure you also handle the edge case where `numberOfParticles` is 1. You don't want to divide by zero.

Comment: I found a problem with this, when I use 1f to 360f it makes the last particle the same as the first.